# Runtime change json property naming strategy with request scoped bean

Tags: java, json, spring, jackson2

I want to drive JSON naming strategy from the request header.
Depending on the value in the request header, I want to set this strategy and similarly should be effective for JSON serialization and deserialization.

eg..

`- If header is "Snake" , request will be {"first_name":"james"}`

`- If header is "Camel" , request will be {"firstName":"james"}`

And, similarly, the response will be serialized for given naming strategy.

I want something like request scoped bean where I can handle this strategy.

```
@Bean
@Scope(value = WebApplicationContext.SCOPE_REQUEST  )
public Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder objectMapperBuilder(
        Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder builder , @Autowired HttpServletRequest request) {


if (null == request || null == builder) {
    return builder;
}
if ("Snake".equals(request.getHeader("Json_naming_strategy"))) {
    builder.propertyNamingStrategy(PropertyNamingStrategy.SNAKE_CASE);
} else {
    builder.propertyNamingStrategy(PropertyNamingStrategy.UPPER_CAMEL_CASE);
}

return builder;
}
```

But with above defination i get this error

> Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '_halObjectMapper': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'objectMapperBuilder': Scope 'request' is not active for the current thread; consider defining a scoped proxy for this bean if you intend to refer to it from a singleton; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request, or processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread? If you are actually operating within a web request and still receive this message, your code is probably running outside of DispatcherServlet/DispatcherPortlet: In this case, use RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current request.

Then i thought of creating another bean as given below. But after defining  following bean, request doesn not come to above defined bean.

```
@Primary
@Bean
public Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder pobjectMapperBuilder() {
Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder builder = new Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder();
builder.serializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL);
return builder;
}
```

Can anyone suggest any solution. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you scan the class or respective package ?

Comment: its scanned , other beans are loaded and  for the bean i declared as primary is also loaded, But i wanted Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder  to be loaded at request scope.